# Multiple waitKey calls not working well with cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I discovered that more than one waitKey calls in an opencv program make it lag out, and all the calls do not get registered properly. You sometimes have to hold some keys for over 4 seconds in order for their code to execute. Said faulty calls work like this:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) == 100:
    show_crop = not show_crop

if cv2.waitKey(1) == 99:
    show_cv = not show_cv

if cv2.waitKey(1) == 116:
    show_curr_track = not show_curr_track
```

The program detects none of the calls at the desired button press, instead you need to hold the said button for multiple seconds, before its code executes. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Call it once in the loop, store the result in a variable, and use that variable in your multiple `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in my program, and decided to answer this question Q&A style!
I came up with a very simple workaround.
First, use a single waitKey call to get the key required as so-

`inp = waitKey(1)`

Now, create a dictionary with its keys as the ordinals of the buttons you're pressing, and values as the code you want to execute (use ; for multiline code, or break the code into a separate function)-

```
d_exec = {
27: "cap.release();cv2.destroyAllWindows();break;",
100:"show_crop = not show_crop", 
99:"show_cv = not show_cv", 
116:"show_curr_track = not show_curr_track", 
115:"save()"
}
```

Here, 27 is Esc,
99 is c,
116 is t,
115 is s on the keyboard for my system and so on. You can also use the ord function if you don't know the actual integer values for keys.

Finally, you can use just the single waitKey function in conjugation with your dictionary, and the inbuilt `exec` function as follows-

```
inp = cv2.waitKey(1)
if inp in d_exec:
    exec(d_exec[inp])
inp = None
```

Here, the exec function takes in a string as an input, and runs it as python code.

**NOTE: Use ; for multiline code (as shown in dictionary line 1), or break it into single line function calls.**

Make sure to set `inp` back to None or some other out of dictionary value, so that the same code doesn't accidentally execute on the next iteration of the main loop.

You can also use the more traditional if else series beneath `inp = waitKey(1)`, but the dictionary method looks more cleaner to me :)

Comment: Storing to code to execute in strings kinda smells to me. It will defeat any static analysis, and will incur extra overhead (probably not relevant here, but still), since it has to parse that string (and then compile) every single time you call `exec`. I'd stick with a sequence of if-statements (or if you have recent enough Python, I think there's now an equivalent of `switch` statement available as well).

Comment: Wow I never really thought of it that way. I was too excited to get an exec statement rolling in there, since that's something I just learnt. Thanks to your comment I now know there's a match-case function in python. The more you know :) Also, don't you think that if the amount of if else statements was large, it would be rather quicker to use the dictionary method instead, assuming memory isn't a concern?